# How to display elements out of order vuetify

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vuetify.js, v-for

Still kind of new to vue/vuetify and firebase, trying to find some logical ideas/answers on this.

My goal is to add additional fields into the form, which these fields have been premade in firebase db. I've added the fields in firebase and of course they're last in the array. So when I loop the fields array from firebase, it displays on the browser in order.
**e.x:**
[Fullname, Gender, Date, Email, FirstName, LastName...]

**VSCode**

[image: loop]

As you can see on my VSCode I'd like to show FirstName first, LastName second and so on...

**Browser**

[image: browser]

My initial thoughts were to go into firebase and manually rearrange the field's values, but I feel that would be inefficient and perhaps malpractice (especially if there was a larger document of fields).

My research says to use lodash and orderBy computation but I'd like to find other potential answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add order to the field object and sort them by order with array.sort

Comment: when you say "add order to the field object", do you mean on firebase or in vscode??
any recommendations for array.sort??
for example, say i want [FirstName, LastName, Gender, Birthdate, FullName, Email...]

i feel like trying to sort by indexes would be sloppy like [13, 12, 5, 4, 0...]